# Как разместить div под div внутри div

Tags: css3

```css
.InscriptionID {
  background: rgba(146, 147, 155, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 200px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.block:before,
.block:after,
.border:before,
.border:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  content: '';
  border-color: #06db34;
  border-style: solid;
}

.block:before {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.block:after {
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.border:before {
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

.border:after {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="InscriptionID" id="namesID">Светлана</div>
</div>
```

Получается вот такой результат и я ни как не могу переместить надпись под рамку
[image: Получается вот такой результат и я ни как не могу переместить надпись под рамку]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.InscriptionID {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(146, 147, 155, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  top: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 200px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.block:before,
.block:after,
.border:before,
.border:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  content: '';
  border-color: #06db34;
  border-style: solid;
}

.block:before {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.block:after {
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.border:before {
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

.border:after {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="InscriptionID" id="namesID">Светлана</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.InscriptionID {
background: rgba(146, 147, 155, 0.6);
color: #fff;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 105px;
}
```